# I am having issues printing a specified regex group from dates in a csv date column - type error - Python

Tags: python-3.x

Summary: I am trying to return the year from all dates in a Date column from a csv file using regex group, but getting a TypeError in response.

csv file headers : Name, LastName, Position, Date
date format : '2012-02-19'

```
file = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in file:
        x = row[3].strip()
        result = re.search(r'([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})',x)
        print(result[1])


TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable 


Expected result : 
2012
2013
2019
2020


Notes: 

# 1) Code above - Performed a check on type returned, type 'str' was correct.
x = row[3].strip()
print(type(x))

<class 'str'>

# 2) Checked my regex match, year 2012 was correctly printed
x = '2012-02-19'

result = re.search(r"([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})",x)
print(result[1])

2012

# 3) Results of print(result)
<re.Match object; span=(0, 10), match='2012-05-04'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 10), match='2013-05-15'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 10), match='2019-03-13'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 10), match='2020-03-13'>
```

Comment: Can you check what's the content of `x` ? Because the errors comes from a non matching result which is `None` can't be subscriptable.

Comment: print(x) all dates are printed from the csv file, excluding all other column data .    2019-01-05
2020-01-06
2019-02-03
2012-05-04
2017-02-02
etc.

Comment: According to the documentation in https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-contents a row could be an object, so I would try to cast x to string str(x).

Comment: That's what I was thinking but getting the string type when determining type for x.  print(type(x))  <class 'str'> . However tried the cast and still getting same response.

Comment: Looks like possible issue with the downloaded .csv file on my mac, all other .csv files work just fine with my script

Comment: I remember struggling with some "invisible characters" that mac generates for no reason. Another approach for this case, just to get different results and investigate what's happening is to use x_split = x.split('-') and then print('x[0]') and see what is printing. I think it is pretty obvious that your regex is fine and working for other files, so there is something wrong with the output of that row. Also, did you tried to skip the first row?

Comment: Looks like there were invisible characters after all , Thanks so much NoiK